# Objects to Array

Tags: javascript

I need to push keys of obj into the array, what is wrong with my code:

```
function getAllKeys(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  var sample = {
  name : 'Sam',
  age : 25,
  hasPets : true
}
  for(var key in obj){
    arr.push(obj[key])
  }
  return arr;
}
getAllKeys()
```

Comment: Move the `sample` object outside the function and pass argument to the function `getAllKeys(sample)`.

Comment: Just use the inbuilt method [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Check my answer below.

Comment: Please click edit under your post and add what you expected the code to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var sample = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 25,
  hasPets: true
}

console.log(Object.keys(sample));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllKeys(obj) {
  var arr = [];

  arr = Object.keys(obj);
  return arr;

}
getAllKeys({
  name : 'Sam',
  age : 25,
  hasPets : true
})
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain how your changes fix/improve the code in question.

Comment: `arr.push(obj[key])` appends value, not key